# Modifying SKS Race Blade Long for solid axle hubs

Tags: fixed-gear, single-speed, commuting-bike, fenders, modification

I have a set of SKS Race Blade Long fenders. They have quick release attachments that fit around QR skewers. Unfortunately, I'd like to set these fenders up on my single speed commuter which has track hubs with solid axles (standard diameters of 9mm up front, and 10mm in the rear).

Initial idea: drill the holes in the fender quick release tabs with a battery powered drill to fit around the track hubs' solid axles.

However, I've also seen suggestions for using a round file instead of drilling, or just p-clamps and abandoning the qr tabs. Anyone have any experience that would care to give their thoughts?

Comment: P clamps are the safe solution here.   Drilling holes is pretty permanent.  You can trial ideas with zip ties, and the black UV rated ones should last several years perfectly well.

Answer (score 1):

If you enlarged the hole on those, there's really not going to be much material left. I'd worry about it getting mashed to nothing under the nuts.

The other thing is that the knurled surface and generous dropout contact area on track nuts do a lot to keep the back wheel in place. Messing with that seems bad.

I would use either p-clamps or, if possible, an appropriately sized random plastic bracket.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a name for those clamps?   Something I can google ?    I have a similar need to OP now.

Comment: @Criggie They're the Cateye SP series light brackets (SP-7 etc).